# AngularJs: remove element from array on decreasing count

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following AngularJs code to change the number of items based on the count.

```
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("sub", [], function() {});
        app.controller("my_ctrl", function($scope) {
          $scope.range = function(n) {
            return new Array(n);
          };
          $scope.submit = function() {
            console.log($scope.config);
          };
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="sub" ng-controller="my_ctrl">
      <form ng-submit="submit()">
        item count:
        <input type="number" min="0" max="10" ng-model="config.no_of_items"/>
        <div ng-repeat="i in range(config.no_of_items) track by $index">
          item name:
          <input name="item" ng-model="config.items[$index]"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      <form>
    </body>
```

It's working when I increase the count and add new items.

But when I decrease the count, the number of input boxes changes, but the element is not removed from the items array.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Then use an "on change listener" on your number input and manually set the array length when it's triggered...

Comment: @Julo0sS, I thought about it, but I need to do this in lot of places. If there's no simple alternative, I'll do this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your code using `ng-change`. So whenever you change the input, an equal number of objects corresponding the count entered will be created and `ng-repeat` will loop over this.

```js
var app = angular.module("sub", [], function() {});
app.controller("my_ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.range = function(count) {
        $scope.config = {
            items: []
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            $scope.config.items.push({});
        }
    };
    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.config);
    };
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="sub" ng-controller="my_ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="submit()"> item count:
        <input type="number" min="0" max="10" ng-model="config.no_of_items" ng-change="range(config.no_of_items)" />
        <div ng-repeat="i in config.items track by $index"> item name:
            <input name="item" ng-model="i.name" /> </div>
        <input type="submit" />
        <form>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm calling the `range` function in lot of places, so will pass the array name also as an argument and try it. Thanks :)

Comment: When you are reducing the value of count and if you know from which index the array should be spliced, then you don't have to reinitialize the arry in range function. You can just splice off the array from a particular index

Answer (score -1):

You can use the angular `limitTo` filter on your `ng-repeat` which should do exactly what you need to do.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in config.items track by $index | limitTo: config.no_of_items">
   item name: <input name="item" ng-model="item" />
</div>
```

The above might not work exactly (been a while since I used Angular 1.x) but its what I would use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't remove the element on decreasing count.

Comment: So you're wanting to actually remove the item from the array - not just hide it from view? Then yes - in that case you'll need the ng-change directive set on the `config.no_of_items` input.